# How do Managed hosting companies create unique static ips for users to connect A Records? Google Cloud

Tags: dns, ip, load-balancing, google-cloud-dns, domain-mapping

I have a service where I build websites for clients and host them on my Kubernetes cluster on Google GKE.

My question is how do hosting platforms automatically assign unique IPv4 IPS to connect A records for each registered user?

My current setup is every single site connects their A records to my load balancers 1.2.3.4.5.6 IP. Recently I learned doing this is bad for SEO for the sites.

One solution I have is to Reserve unique ips for each website through Google Cloud then forward them to my loadbalancer is this a good, scalable solution, or how large hosting companies with millions of unique sites do it? or is there an alternative?

Potentially I can have 100's or thousands of reserved IPS for each website

Comment: Using one IP for multiple websites is very common. Search engines are smart enough to know the difference. There is a lot of bad SEO advice on the Internet.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks I would still like to know the how large corporations do it. Not sure if GCP have limits for how many reserved IPS  an account can have.

Comment: 1) Large corporations do not allocate multiple IP addresses unless absolutely necessary. 2) Google Cloud has a quota for IP addresses which can be increased. 3) Just deploy an HTTP load balancer with multiple frontends. Each frontend has its own global IP address. 4) Deploying multiple IP addresses is very easy to do, given the extreme shortage of address space, there are zero good reasons to do it.

Comment: @Jeanloriston was your question already resolved? If so, please post it as an answer so that other community members with similar questions can also see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Per @JohnHanley 's answers to your questions:

Using one IP for multiple websites is very common. Search engines are smart enough to know the difference.

1. Large corporations do not allocate multiple IP addresses unless absolutely necessary.
2. Google Cloud has a [quota](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota#quotas) for IP addresses which can be increased.
3. Just deploy an [HTTP load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https) with multiple frontends. Each frontend has its own global IP address.
4. Deploying multiple IP addresses is very easy to do, given the extreme shortage of address space, there are zero good reasons to do it.